# generate set cookie in a bad time for php at session_set_save_handler function

Tags: php, http, session, cookies

When I access an action for get some cookie, I have two way for realize the goal.
    But I won't access the action directly.
    One is use fiddler2 to build a http request, the other is writting some code in php to simulate a HTTP request.The following code is my implementation:

the action: www.example.com/account/login
    account is controller,login is action, I use MVC.

when I use fiddler, I build a request, like following,

```
*******************************************************
POST http://localhost/account/Login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 67
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost/lm006/home/index.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

username=admin&password=fsdfsdafdss
*******************************************************
```

When I use PHP, I write code like this,

```
*******************************************************
$method="POST"
$option = array('http' => array(
                'method' => $method,
                'header' => "User-Agent:Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.04506; CIBA)\r\nAccept:*/*\r\nReferer:" . $referer,
            ));
if ($method==='POST')
     $option['http']=array_merge($option['http'], array('content' => http_build_query($postdata)));
$files=file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($option));
preg_match_all("/Set-Cookie:(.*?)\r\n/", implode("\r\n", $http_response_header), $cookies);
*******************************************************
```

The very strange thing is, if I use fiddler to get cookie, I will get request like

```
***************************************************************************
array (
  0 => 'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5',
  1 => 'Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT',
  2 => 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
  3 => 'Pragma: no-cache',
  4 => 'Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2b4v30vuglap0sid2rtitgmeh0; path=/',
)
***************************************************************************
```

here just One Set-Cookie

If I use PHP, I will get request:

```
***************************************************************************
array (
  0 => 'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5',
  1 => 'Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=7fdvb0vaasdp0sid2rti234ap1; path=/',
  2 => 'Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT',
  3 => 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
  4 => 'Pragma: no-cache',
  5 => 'Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2b4v30vuglap0sid2rtitgmeh0; path=/',
)
***************************************************************************
```

Here is two Set-Cookie!!!

I trace the code in X-Debug.
  I find the situation:

```
<i>

    $header1=headers_list();

    @session_set_save_handler(array($this,'openSession'),array($this,'closeSession'),array($this,'readSession'),array($this,'writeSession'),array($this,'destroySession'),array($this,'gcSession'));

    $header2=headers_list();

</i>
```

the $header1 is 'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5' for both way.

the $header2 for fiddler way is

```
************************************************
array (
  0 => 'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5',
  1 => 'Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT',
************************************************
```

the $header2 for PHP way is

```
******************************************************************
array (
  0 => 'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5',
  1 => 'Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=7fdvb0vaasdp0sid2rti234ap1; path=/',
  2 => 'Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT',
*******************************************************************
```

HERE WE GET AN ADDITIONAL SET-COOKIE ITEM!!!

It's too strange, hope for your help.

Thank a lot.